# parsing finacle core banking xml response in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to get the value of status of response and available balance from xml returned from finacle core banking.

xml is at:
[https://pastebin.com/8bvpuUGp](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I'm trying to get the value as below, but nothing appeared.

```
xroot = ET.fromstring(xml)
for ab in xroot.findall('AVAIL'):
    bal = ab.find('AVAIL').text
    print(bal)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the exact expected output?

Comment: expected is what is available balance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to get the balance for this `'AVAIL'` query.
You seem to be referring to a tag name, though it's a text contained within tag. Furthermore it does not have any child items, so your search does not work.

I'm not an expert in xml, but here is a working code I've come up with:

```python
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

term = 'AVAIL'

xroot = ET.fromstring(xml)
el = [element for element in xroot.iter() for child in element if child.text == term]
for i in [element for element in el[0].iter() if element.text != term]:
    if len(i.text) > 1:
        print(re.sub('{.*}', '', i.tag), i.text)
```

###### Otput:

```console
amountValue 16299.37
currencyCode NPR
```

Here I find a child that contains text "AVAIL", than accesses a parent element and cycle though it's children to find everything except the query. Seems like this is the info you were looking for.

### Update

> i got value using `if(i.text != 'NPR'): print(float(i.text))`. Would you please also find if Status == 'SUCCESS'

If you only need the amount we can skip filtering out `!=` text and search for the tag instead.
This and checking for status will result in:

```python
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xroot = ET.fromstring(xml)

statuses = [el for el in xroot.iter() if re.sub('{.*}', '', el.tag) == 'Status']
success = True if any(el.text == 'SUCCESS' for el in statuses) else False

if success:
    bal = [el for el in xroot.iter() for ch in el if ch.text == 'AVAIL']
    for i in [el for el in bal[0].iter() if re.sub('{.*}', '', el.tag) == 'amountValue']:
        print(float(i.text))
```

###### Output:

```console
16299.37
```

Comment: thank you so much. i got value using if(i.text != 'NPR'):
         print(float(i.text)). Would you please also find if Status == 'SUCCESS'